# Is it okay to cut a notch into cross brace?

Tags: walls, receptacle

I've only lived in Canada for 4 years and am not sure what their codes are.

I live in a duplex in Montreal-North and was surprised to see the cross brace.

I cut the hole to install an outlet behind my wall mounted TV.

[image]

Comment: this looks like a fire block to me (a series of 2x in the wall to prevent fire from traveling up the inside of the wall)

Comment: Fifty years ago, my father build a bedroom for me in our unfinished basement in Montreal. I recall that he put these horizontal braces in the wall at that time. They were put between every stud. I had always assumed they were to reinforce the wall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that is a fire block it may be very convenient to notch it to just the right depth. With the right kind of metal electrical box you could get a secure box attachment by screwing through the back of the box into the fire block.

Comment: Unfortunately, the wires come in through the back of the electrical box: http://www.canadiantire.ca/en/pdp/leviton-re-work-electrical-box-0521305p.html#.VlyvcIQ2sng

Comment: Rectangular electrical boxes almost always have the wire entry at the very top and bottom rear corners if the box. It seems like there would be space above or below the fire block to accommodate the wire entry to the box.

Comment: +1 or put a box horizontally, below the fire break.

Comment: This box: http://www.homedepot.com/p/Carlon-1-Gang-21-cu-in-Non-Metallic-Wall-Box-with-Adjustable-Bracket-B121ADJ-40R/202077339 horizontally. (Tin snips will remove the hook at the end of the metal bracket that'll get in your way.) And parenthetically, I can't believe what crappy tyre is charging for those metal boxes linked in the first comment.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you do, damage control.

Make sure you have a clean shot down the wall from the fireblock or whatever it is to the outlet below.

Put a low voltage mounting ring and a duckbill on this hole.  See [this answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/78678/replace-existing-phone-jack-with-network-cable/78695#78695) for a picture of those.  Use this to run up your HDMI.

edit:  since you don't want to run HDMI or other audio or video cables to the TV, just put a blank cover rather than a duckbill on the low voltage mounting ring.

If there's enough room for a box AND cover plate mounted horizontally below the fireblock, you're set.  It doesn't look to me like there's enough room.  So lower the mount so that the top piece is right on the duckbill, see if that gets you enough room.

Comment: It's for an electrical outlet (high voltage), not HDMI cables (low voltage)

Comment: You're going to need both, right? Or is this TV only for off the air / broadcast content?  Not going to connect to xbox, roku, cable TV / satellite TV box, etc?

Comment: No. It's for my bedroom. I only have the TV and an Apple TV which is mounted behind the TV.